# MS Graph Update/Set Excel value in a cell

Tags: excel, api, microsoft-graph-api

I haven't found any example to update/insert a value in one cell of an specific worksheet with Microsoft Graph API.

Is this in general possible?

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and then [edit] your question.**

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, using single cell reference.
Send `PATCH` request to (for example) one drive workbook:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets('one_of_your_worksheet_name')/cell(row=0,column=0)
```

Request body example:

```js
{
 "values": [ ["I am cell A:1"] ],
 "valueTypes": [ ["String"]]
}
```

Comment: If you're like me and built a system using lettered columns like excel displays and don't want these zero-indexed values, use the range update with a single address e.g. /workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1') and send in a response identical to this. Works for updating a single cell by address, not row/column index.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with Microsoft Graph. If the cell is in a 'well-known' address, you can PATCH the cell values by making a PATCH request to `~/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')`.

See [range update documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/range_update) for additional detail.